# Installing alongside windows on raid 0

Tags: raid, windows-10

I currently have Windows 10 on 2x150gb raid 0 configuration (plus 2x1,5tb hdds with data, not raid) and want to install the latest ubuntu from dvd.
If I choose the first option (to install alongside them), I am presented with only one drive option which is one of my 1,5 tb "data" drives. 
If I choose the third option (something else) it seems it doesnt recognize my raid.. Pls advise.

[image: Installation Picture]

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using software RAID, right?  If so, you need to either purchase a hardware RAID card, or sacrifice your RAID setup for Ubuntu.

You can buy hardware RAID controllers for as little as $20, and they also improve RAID performance.  Alternatively you can trash the RAID to install Ubuntu, or a 3rd option: add another HDD in there and install to that.

Comment: Ty for your response, I am not very familiar with raid, i just recently set this up. I have a Asus P6T Deluxe M/B and set the raid from boot with ctrl-L. I would think that is not software raid but u tell me.

I already have other hdds in the system but how would that solve the problem? if I choose to install ubuntu on a third drive, still it would need to install grub on the same drive as windows, no?

Comment: "The motherboard comes with the Intel® ICH10R Southbridge controller that supports RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 10, and RAID 5 for six independent Serial ATA channels".  I am guessing this is the hardware u were referring to

Comment: It could be HW raid.  If you install Ubuntu to another drive, and then install the bootloader on that same drive, you can set the BIOS to boot to that drive first, which will give your GRUB and let you pick an OS.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

It is hardware raid, and the solution was very simple after all. I just had to resize the NTFS partition on the raid 0 drives. I used Acronis and left 80sth gigs of free space which showed as such in the installation. I ended up choosing the automated installation and everything works fine now. Hope my experience helps someone, and thank you Daniel for your responses.

:)